# Microsoft Edge: local/session storage are not working in a new tab

Tags: tabs, microsoft-edge

I'm working on a Web Application hosted in Azure.  I've tried it on MS Edge (build 20.10525.0.0) and got the following problem.

I have a link with target _blank to open in a new tab a page. On the click event of this link, I store some data in the session storage.  The new page is retrieving the data to display it.  This work fine under Chrome, Firefox, IE 9-10-11.

Under Edge, the storage seems to work fine.  Thought, the retrieving is not always working.  Sometimes, the first attempt works. Sometimes, it returns null.

I've tried to use the local storage instead of session storage.  I've also tried to use window.open instead to the target _blank. Both of these solutions are not working.

Anyone have ideas ?

Comment: Unfortunately, something is indeed wrong with localStorage in new Microsoft Edge. I've come across the similar problem and it seems that this pretty straightforward demo http://html5demos.com/storage-events works everywhere except Edge. I'm wondering why this hasn't been posted yet.

Comment: I've created a MS Edge bug for that: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedbackdetail/view/1798743/localstorage-bug

Comment: @Buzinas, any updates on this? it's now Sep 2017 and on my Edge 38.14393 i still don't recieve a storage event when in an ifram the localStroge is changed.

Comment: I am still having the same issue, IE edge unable to delete local storage in new Tab? is this resolved and if yes how?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with localStorage across multiple tabs - it would only work intermittently, or not at all. My solution was to switch to `window.indexedDB` (see [docs on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB)) which works fine in IE10, IE11 and MS Edge (tested on Edge v20.10240).

Answer (score 0):

If window A created window B then the storage event gets trigger

try it out with this code

create a file called a.htm and add this script in

```
(function() {
    function write(s) {
        var d = document.createElement('div');
        d.innerHTML = s;
        document.body.appendChild(d);
    }

    var w = window.open('','window_b');
    if (w.location.host === '') {
        w.location.href = 'http://localhost/b.htm';
    }

    if (window.localStorage) {
        setInterval(function() {
            var now = (new Date()).toTimeString();
            localStorage.removeItem('date');
            localStorage.setItem('date', now);
            write('fired on ' + now);
        }, 3000);
    }
    else {
        write('local storage not detected!');
    }
})();
```

create a file called b.htm and add this script

```
(function() {
    function write(s) {
        var d = document.createElement('div');
        d.innerHTML = s;
        document.body.appendChild(d);
    }

    window.addEventListener('storage', function(e) {  
        e.newValue && write('received ' + e.newValue);
    });

})();
```

then just browse to a.htm